# Which batteries are compatible with the DeWalt DW9107?

Tags: drill, battery

I have a DeWalt battery charger model# DW9107.  Which batteries can I charge in it? It says 14.4volts

I have a DeWalt hammer drill model# DCD950B.  Will the battery for it, DC9096 work with my charger? It says 18volts.

Comment: Vote to put on hold, off topic.

Comment: @WarLoki is there a more appropriate StackExchange to ask this question?

Comment: Have you tried contacting DeWalt?

Comment: I have submitted a ticket with them but have not heard back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From DeWalt support:

Unfortunately it looks like the battery charger will not charge a 18 volt battery that will work with the DCD950b. The charger charges up to a 14.4 volt battery and the DCD950 will take a 18 volt battery. The battery and charger you will need for the DCD950 is  Charger 388683-12 and battery DC9096.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I tried the same thing. I have a dw9107 charger, and the 18v battery won't fit. I modified the battery casing a little and it charged the 18v battery just fine. I don't recommend this as I'm sure isn't recommended by Dewalt! just a little personal experience. 14.4 is only 3.6v from 18 so what the heck it worked.

Comment: Plus one for obsoleting planned obsolescence.

Comment: These are NiCd batteries, so the worst that would happen is you might trash the battery. Don't try something like this with Lithium batteries; the worst could be a serious fire.